# Clear value of input type date in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, date, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge displays a HTML5 date picker to enter values for inputs defined by

```
<input type="date">
```

Is there a way to show a clear button or an 'x' decoration to delete the value afterwards, like it is done by Google Chrome?

Comment: If your affected by this, be sure to go vote at uservoice https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/18411796-date-input-should-allow-the-entry-of-empty-string

Comment: New feature request link is here: https://microsoftedge.uservoice.com/forums/928828-developer/suggestions/40695781-add-an-input-date-clear-button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best option here is probably to hide the custom clear mark provided by Chrome, and provide your own for all browsers to use instead:

```
input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}
```

You would then provide your own *clear* button:

```
<input type="date" required />
<button>Clear</button>
```

And finally, a small piece of logic to clear the input whenever the button is clicked:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var elmnt = document.querySelector( "input" );
    var clear = document.querySelector( "button" );

    clear.addEventListener( "click", function ( event ) {
        elmnt.value = "";
    });

}());
```

I hope this helps.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zcay9qc5/

Comment: Ok, that works. But I am still surprised that Microsoft Edge supports input type date, but does not offer a clear button.

Comment: @Michael When IE 10 shipped we (I work on the Microsoft Edge team) added clear buttons to just about every form element. Many developers were upset, because they *already* had clear buttons in their UI. It's possible we tried *learning our lesson* this time around ;)

Comment: @Sampson thank you for the workaround for developers. Based on your comment to Michael (which I realize is really old) I feel like the Edge team missed the point. **The issue isn't that there is no clear button. The issue is that there is no way to clear a date field without some workaround provided by a developer.** If I could select the date text and hit Backspace or Delete then I wouldn't be commenting, but I can't even do that.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the simple example from [Where did the clear button go on date type input elements in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135055/where-did-the-clear-button-go-on-date-type-input-elements-in-chrome).

```
<input id=el type=datetime-local value="2025-07-01T12:44">
<button onclick="javascript:el.value=''">X</button>
```

And turned it into an extension method in my C# ASP.NET web application.

```
public static System.Web.IHtmlString editorWithClearFor<TModel, TValue>(
  this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
  object additionalViewData )
{
  //------------------------------
  // Determine the input element ID.
  // The ID might be the property name.
  ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression( expression, helper.ViewData );
  string inputElemId =  metadata.PropertyName;

  //------------------------------
  // The ID might be specified in the HTML attributes within the view data.
  Type t = additionalViewData.GetType();
  PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty( "htmlAttributes" );
  IDictionary<string, object> attribs = pi.GetValue( additionalViewData, null ) as IDictionary<string, object>;
  if ( attribs.ContainsKey( "id" ) )
  {
    inputElemId = attribs["id"].ToString();
  }

  //------------------------------
  // For the input and the button to be side by side,
  // must I must wrap each of them in a div?  That seems to be the only thing that works.

  //------------------------------
  // Input.
  IHtmlString input = helper.EditorFor( expression, additionalViewData );

  //------------------------------
  // Wrap the input in a div.
  TagBuilder div1 = new TagBuilder( "div" );
  div1.MergeAttribute( "style", "display: inline-block;" );
  div1.InnerHtml = input.ToString();

  //------------------------------
  // Clear button.
  TagBuilder btn = new TagBuilder( "button" );
  btn.MergeAttribute( "title", "Clear" );
  btn.MergeAttribute( "style", "border: none; background-color: transparent;" );
  btn.MergeAttribute( "onclick", String.Format( "javascript:{0}.value=''", inputElemId ) );
  btn.InnerHtml = "X";

  //------------------------------
  // Wrap the button in a div.
  TagBuilder div2 = new TagBuilder( "div" );
  div2.MergeAttribute( "style", "display: inline-block;" );
  div2.InnerHtml = btn.ToString();

  //------------------------------
  // Concatenate.
  Debug.WriteLine( div1.ToString() + div2.ToString() ); 
  return MvcHtmlString.Create( div1.ToString() + div2.ToString() );
}
```

Example usage in the cshtml markup:

```
@Html.editorWithClearFor( m => m.DueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { "class", "form-control" } } )
```