# Where did the clear button go on date type input elements in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, date, input

Up until last Thursday the date type input elements used to have a clear button (a cross or "x") next to them.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what has changed? How can I get the clear button back?

We are using angular and Chrome as the browser.

The HTML code below shows the problem (when Chrome is used):

```html
<label for="birthdaytime">Birthday (date and time):</label> <input type="datetime-local" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime">
```

Comment: Please provide code so we can troubleshoot your issue. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: <label for="birthdaytime">Birthday (date and time):</label>
<input type="datetime-local" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime">

Comment: Save the above as HTML and open in Chrome

Comment: Please put the code in your question, not in the comment. Use menu on top of your textarea where you type.

Comment: Done - this has now been updated

Comment: In my browser, there is clear button. **Please note that all browsers will show this in their own way**

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: As I said at the start this only changed on the 28/05/2020. It had a clear button in Chrome up to this date. I am trying to find out what changed.

Comment: I am using "Brave" browser.

Answer (score 11):

It was reported as a bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087490#c1

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087501

And someone in the bug discussion suggested a workaround: add a button that will clear the date-local element value:

```html
<input id=el type=datetime-local value="2025-07-01T12:44">
<button onclick="javascript:el.value=''">X</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxpt4r8b/

Comment: I agree with https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087501#c55

Comment: I agree with Ryan, seems a clean solution that Firefox should pick up, too. Adding a custom clear element adds overflow and also the workaround example above requires the CSP unsafe-inline for script-src which in my opinion should be avoided at all cost.